# Formula / decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel - I have the following simple formula:=SUM(B4/A4) for context cell A4 has a value of 4 and cell B4 has a value of 320. 4 / 320 = 0.125

I need 0.125 to convert to 1.25, which I will subtract from 100.00 giving me the final answer of 98.75%

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you have a type some where.  you say A4 has 4 and B4 has 320 but your formula has B4/A4 which is 320/4 not 4/320.  Also the return would be 0.0125 not 0.125.

Comment: If U use either `=1-B4/A4` or even `=1-(B4/A4)` you get `0.9875` and if apply the Percentage format then you get `99%` instead of `98.75%` ,, so better U may try this `=TEXT((1 - B4/A4), "0.00%")` ☺

Comment: Percentage value?

Answer (score 3):

Just do it all in one step:

```
=1-B4/A4
```

This would return `.9875`

And format the cell as percentage. which will then show the decimal as a percentage `98.75%`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked!!!!